# Android Cordova: Cordova Library is not showing

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have created a phone Gap android project via Cordova. I've downloaded Cordova through command line. but not showing CordovaApp_CordovaLib in **Clean** and not in **Project Libraries**.  Kindly help me how Can I resolve this issue? I have attached Screenshots.
[image]

[image]

Here is screenshot When I Right click on Library a

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your Cordova Library. Click Properties. Make sure **is Library** checkbox is checked. [image]

If not do it right away. This makes the Cordova lib as library. Then add this library to your project.

Thanks.

Updated :

[image]

Comment: Why Android tab. Right click on project and click properties

Comment: Yes I did it but Android Tab is not being displayed.I have updated my question last screenshot is what I get when I go to the properties of the Library-

Comment: do you have the android plugin installed? or even better, use the eclipse ADT version

Comment: Yes @jcesarmobile is right. Guess you might have not connected with ADT plugin.

Your 1st screen shows Android view whereas last image doesnot show. it means you might have removed.

Comment: @jcesarmobile rest of my projects also showing JAVAEE and they are working.